# Set default application for mime type on deb file

Tags: deb, packaging, mime-type

I create a deb package using `dpkg-deb` on Ubuntu 20.04, in `myApp.desktop` I added a `MimeType=text/plain;`, but is-it possible to set `myApp` to open by default the file of mime type `text/plain` ?

I need it when the deb package is installed.

Thanks